# How to setup integrator action when using full-state feedback?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

So I have a state-space system,
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\mathbf{x}}&=&A\mathbf{x} + B\mathbf{u}\tag{1}\label{EqSS}\\
\mathbf{y}&=&C\mathbf{x}\\
\end{eqnarray}
where,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{x}&=&\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2& \cdots&x_{11} & x_{12}\end{bmatrix}^\intercal\tag{2}\\
\mathbf{u}&=&\begin{bmatrix}u_1&u_2&u_3 & u_4\end{bmatrix}^\intercal\\
A&\in&\mathbb{R}^{12\times 12}\\
B&\in&\mathbb{R}^{12\times 4}\\
C&=&I\in\mathbb{R}^{12\times 12}
\end{eqnarray}
I am using the following control law for tracking commanded state values $\mathbf{x}^c\in\mathbb{R}^{12\times 1}$,
\begin{equation}\label{EqUctrl}
\mathbf{u}=-K\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^c\right)=K\left(\mathbf{x}^c-\mathbf{x}\right)\tag{3}
\end{equation}
where gains matrix $K\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 12}$ is calculated using the $\texttt{lqr(A,B,Q,N)}$ function in $\texttt{Matlab}$.

It turns out tracking performance is quite good for all states but $x_{12}$ when using my selections for state weight and input weight matrices $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{12\times 12}$ and $R\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$. State $x_{12}$ tends to $x^c_{12}$ as simulation time goes by but is typically offset by say 10 %.

**Questions**

1. How do I go about augmenting an integrator state $\dot{x}_{13}=x^c_{12}-x_{12}$ to \eqref{EqSS} and \eqref{EqUctrl}?
2. My current plan for augmenting an integrator state $\dot{x}_{13}=x^c_{12}-x_{12}$ to \eqref{EqSS} and \eqref{EqUctrl} is to,

   - add a 13th row and column to system matrix $A$ according to,
     \begin{eqnarray}
     \text{Row 13: }&&\begin{bmatrix}
     a_{13,1} & a_{13,2} & \cdots & a_{13,11} & a_{13,12} & a_{13,13}
     \end{bmatrix}\phantom{\hspace{1mm}}=
     \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}\\
     \text{Column 13: }&&\begin{bmatrix}
     a_{1,13} & a_{2,13} & \cdots & a_{11,13} & a_{12,13} & a_{13,13}
     \end{bmatrix}^\intercal=
     \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \phantom{-}0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}
     \end{eqnarray}
   - add a 13th row to input signal matrix $B$ according to,
     \begin{equation}
     \text{Row 13: }\begin{bmatrix}
     b_{13,1} & b_{13,2} & b_{13,3} & b_{13,4}
     \end{bmatrix}
     \end{equation}
   - with the augmented matrices $A,B$ at hand calculate a new gain matrix $K$ for the control law \eqref{EqUctrl}.

   Do these steps seem appropriate to you guys? I am a bit puzzled on how to do this because of the material I have found on the Internet,
   [Lec 6: State Feedback, Controllability, Integral Action (p.31-33)](https://www.control.lth.se/fileadmin/control/Education/EngineeringProgram/FRTF05_China/L6_updated_201811122.pdf)
   [DC Motor Position: State-Space Methods for Controller Design](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorPosition&section=ControlStateSpace)
   What confuses me perhaps is the control law \eqref{EqUctrl} I am using which is a bit different from the often occuring $u=r-K\mathbf{x}$. Perhaps is $u=r-K\mathbf{x}$ applicable to single input systems only, but I guess it depends on how you would specify $r$?
3. As for the control law I am using \eqref{EqUctrl} I found it here,
   [MIT: Maneuvering and Control of Marine Vehicles](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/2-154-maneuvering-and-control-of-surface-and-underwater-vehicles-13-49-fall-2004/2d5318503b8f97d5a5255596fcf2e3f1_lec19.pdf)
   [StackExchange: How to improve reference tracking using state feedback?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/how-to-improve-reference-tracking-using-state-feedback)
   The control law performs well (apart from "that" state) and works nicely with the system description I have in terms of matrix sizes. Can anyone explain how you would expand or re-write $u=r-K\mathbf{x}$ to \eqref{EqUctrl}, derive \eqref{EqUctrl} or perhaps refer to a book or technical paper where this is done? I am more used to seeing $u=r-K\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but AFAIK, LQR is really meant for driving the states towards zero and not towards a commanded value. According to the aircraft example in Matlab's help page for [`lqr()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.lqr.html), they reduce tracking error by increasing the weights for the corresponding state. They appear to provide a different function [`lqgtrack`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.lqgtrack.html) for tracking and it mentions an integrator.

Comment: You’re definitely correct about the purpose of LQR driving states to zero. Perhaps one could view this problem in terms of driving the state vector $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^c$ to zero? I’m going to investigate that I think. As for my idea on integration action it turned out my plan worked, the state tends to the desired value having introduced the augmented integrator state.

Comment: If your implementation worked, you can post it as an answer here. It will help future readers. Self answers are allowed in SE.

Comment: Ah ok. I will try to compile an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm for the system at hand, augmenting an integrator state $\dot{x}_{13}=x^c_{12}-x_{12}$ can successfully be carried out by adding a $13^{\text{th}}$,

1. row and column to system matrix $A$,
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \text{Row 13: }&&\begin{bmatrix}
   a_{13,1} & a_{13,2} & \cdots & a_{13,11} & a_{13,12} & a_{13,13}
   \end{bmatrix}\phantom{\hspace{1mm}}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}\\
   \text{Column 13: }&&\begin{bmatrix}
   a_{1,13} & a_{2,13} & \cdots & a_{11,13} & a_{12,13} & a_{13,13}
   \end{bmatrix}^\intercal=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \phantom{-}0 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \end{eqnarray}
2. row to input signal matrix $B$,
   \begin{equation}
   \text{Row 13: }\begin{bmatrix}
   b_{13,1} & b_{13,2} & b_{13,3} & b_{13,4}
   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \end{equation}

Carrying out 1. and 2. means we have the augmented matrix sizes for the system and the controller,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{x}&=&\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2& \cdots&x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\end{bmatrix}^\intercal\\
\mathbf{u}&=&\begin{bmatrix}u_1&u_2&u_3 & u_4\end{bmatrix}^\intercal\\
A&\in&\mathbb{R}^{13\times 13}\\
B&\in&\mathbb{R}^{13\times 4}\\
C&=&I\in\mathbb{R}^{13\times 13}\\
K&\in&\mathbb{R}^{4\times 13}\\
\end{eqnarray}